# Fetch value using input from user in D3

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from a user input field.

If I write this code, it works fine :

```
data.KM; //KM is the name of the key in json file
```

but if I write

```
var xA = "KM";

data.xA;
```

it returns `undefined`.

Please help me to implement the second way as I want to take this value (in place of KM), from the user and make a graph depending on the user's input and not just KM. (Note :- there are 25 other such keys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a property by its name, you need [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
var xA = "KM";
data[xA];  // this will give access to the property named "KM"
```

This cannot be done by applying [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) as in your example, because this does not allow for referencing the property's name by a variable.